# Dimension of an A module bounded by dimension as a k vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let A be a k-algebra and V be an A-module which is also a k-vector space (I believe this extra assumption is necessary if we don't know A to be a unital algebra?). Moreover, let V have finite k-dimension. Is the dimension of V as an A-module bounded by its k-dimension?
I am confident of this in the case where our algebra is a group algebra, though, I have not written a proof down.

Comment: What "dimension" of a module are you talking about? Every chain of $A$ submodules is a chain of $k$ submodules. How are you going to find a longer chain in the first poset than in the second poset?

Comment: I think you can probably already write this proof, if you just try it.